# SQLite DateTime query - why it doesnt work?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have below table in my SQLite DB.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [TICK] (                               
TS          DATETIME        NOT NULL,
PRICE       DECIMAL(10,3)   NOT NULL
);
```

Im trying to filter out given date & time range - for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TICK t  WHERE ts between   '2017-01-25 21:44:13'  AND '2017-03-21 16:35:14'
```

But this returns 1st record with ts=2017-01-26  08:00:00, while '2017-01-25  21:45:12' is expected

I can improve that by casting ts as DateTime:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TICK t  WHERE datetime( ts) between   '2017-01-25 21:44:13'  AND '2017-03-21 16:35:14'
```

But I dont understand why I need to do that (if TS column is already DateTime Type) ?

Also performance of such query is 10x slower than 1st one

Please advise how to deal with TimeStamps in Sqlite... (I havent such issues in other DB engines)

Example data:

```
TS                  |PRICE   |
--------------------+--------+
2017-01-30  08:00:00|2293.598|
2017-01-30  08:01:00| 2287.14|
2017-01-30  08:02:00|2287.194|
2017-01-30  08:03:00|2287.335|
2017-01-30  08:04:00| 2287.23|
2017-01-30  08:05:00|2287.078|
2017-01-30  08:06:00|2287.156|
2017-01-30  08:07:00|2287.063|
2017-01-30  08:08:00|2286.782|
```

Comment: There is no DATETIME data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Post sample data of your table.

Comment: @forpas - why then I could use that in DDL and why this is working when I do casting

Comment: You can use **anything** as a data type. Try `CREATE TABLE t(x anything)`. It works in SQLite. Read the documentation in the link of my previous comment. Also read this: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Do you really have 2 spaces between the date and time in the column TS? If so, change it to exactly 1 space.

Comment: Ogh - Indeed I have 2 spaces! I have overlooked that! Thanks ! In fact I didnt put much attention on that because I thought it is controlled by field type anyway... Now I know its not 'real' DateTime service... So what would be then most efficient way to keep and query date and time by Sqlite ? I have pretty large tables and performance is key for this app

Comment: You can use strings for ISO datetimes in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` (1 space only between date and time), or integers for unixepoch datetimes (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00) or real numbers for Julian day numbers. Any of those work with SQLite's datetime functions. Also add an index for the TS column.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing this up for others' benefit

Ive learnt that:

- **SQLlite does not really have DateTime type**,
- but DDL allows to create such field type
- Ive overlooked **I had 2 spaces between date and time** - what caused issue
- As Sqlite doesn't have such type you cannot count on it it will be controlling what you put into such field

**All credits to @forpas**